# Create multiselect dropdown menu in plotly without using dash

Tags: python, plotly, multi-select

I am using `plotly` in a project and I want to create `multiselect dropdown menu` in plotly without using `dash module`. I actually can create `dropdown menu` but I don't know if it is possible to create `multiselect dropdown menu`. This is a part of my code:

```
    # Add dropdown
    fig.update_layout(
        updatemenus=[
            dict(
                active=0,
                buttons=list([
                
                    dict(label="All",
                         method="update",
                         args=[{"visible": [True, True, True, True]},
                               {"title": "Both"}]),
                
                    dict(label="Data 1",
                         method="update",
                         args=[{"visible": [True, False, True, True]},
                               {"title": "Data 1",
                                }]),
                
                    dict(label="Data 2",
                         method="update",
                         args=[{"visible": [True, True, False, True]},
                               {"title": "Data 2",
                                }]),
                
                       dict(label="Data 3",
                         method="update",
                         args=[{"visible": [True, True, True, False]},
                               {"title": "Data 3",
                        }]),
                 
                 ]),
                            
                direction="down",
                pad={"r": 10, "t": 10},
                showactive=True,
                x=0.0,
                xanchor="left",
                y=1.15,
                yanchor="top"

            )
        ])
```

What is your opinion? Is it possible to create a `multi select dropdown` menu in such case?